# PYTHON - convert special character to string

Tags: python, char, hex, character

I need help. Is there any option how to disable implicit convert special characters?
I mean:

```
#this is normal way with implicit convert special character
value = '\x55'
print value
>>> U
#and I would like to work with this value like with a string
print value
>>> \x55
```

Comment: Something like `print r'\x55'`?

Comment: @ŠimonKostolný: Can you maybe accept an answer in order to mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use raw string:

```
value = r'\x55'
```

Answer (score 0):

format the `ord` character with `{:x}` formatting.

```
>>> print '\\x{:x}'.format(ord(value))
\x55
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there is a problem. For example, when user on any web site(on any blog) put this string to input field.

```
<input name='msg' type='text' value='\x55'>
```

how to encode this value to raw '\x55'
I mean, any special character, just not exactly hex

There is whole code from web.py framework

```
import web
ulrs = ('/reg', Reg)

class Reg:
    def POST(self):
        request = web.input(msg=None)
        return request.msg
>>> U
```